# How to a remove substring that starts and ends with a certain word?

Tags: teradata

i am trying to use  teradata `regex_replace` to remove all subsrtings that start with a word `DOCNAME` and end with a character `;`

Here is what I tried

```
SEL REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, 'DOCNAME(.*?);','',1,0,'i') new_txt  
FROM testTable
;
```

But this is not doing anything . Where is the problem ?

---

Here is my String

`PUBLIC(verify nbr); OWNER(test schedule); DOCNAME(infrastructure); OWNER(get inventory); DOCNAME(null); DOCNAME(inventory); PRAC(inventory);`

The query above returns the same string, but i need the `DOCNAME(...);` removed (there are 3 docnames above, all need to be removed)

Comment: you should add to your post some example data so people can verify your regex is correct, and/or do their own tests

Comment: Thank you . I added my string. I used the exact same regex in java and it worked . How come it doesn't work in teradata ?

Comment: There are different dialects of regex, Teradata supports mostly the Perl variation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a backslash in front of the parens to make the regex engine see literal paren characters else the regex engine thinks you are defining a group.  Try this:

```
SEL REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, 'DOCNAME\(.*?\);','',1,0,'i') new_txt  
FROM testTable
;
```

Note that this will leave 2 spaces between the remaining list elements. I suspect it doesn't matter, but if it does, you'll need to add a space to the beginning or end of your REGEXP_STRING.

Note also if the REGEXP_REPLACE doesn't appear to do anything, then the regex didn't find a match and returns the original input string.  That's a clue your regexp_string is wrong if you are sure the input is correct.

Comment: The question mark is vital, otherwise the `.*` gets greedy. Btw, this can be further simplified to `'DOCNAME.*?;'`